# Application can't find view when using areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am experimenting with Areas and I have an ajax call that calls an action
but when trying to return a Partialview it says it can not find it:

[image]

UserAreaRegistration.cs :

```
public class UsersAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "Users";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            name: "User",
            url: "User",
            defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "CreateUser" }
        );
        context.MapRoute(
            "Users_default",
            "Users/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

In my user controller I tried:

```
[RouteArea("User")]
public class UserController : Controller
{}
```

the action:

```
    public ActionResult GetUsrForm()
    {
        var model = new UserMod();

        return PartialView("testUUU");
    }
```

but i still get:

> The partial view 'testUUU' was not found or no view engine supports
>   the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
>   ~/Views/User/testUUU.aspx ~/Views/User/testUUU.ascx
>   ~/Views/Shared/testUUU.aspx ~/Views/Shared/testUUU.ascx
>   ~/Views/User/testUUU.cshtml ~/Views/User/testUUU.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/testUUU.cshtml ~/Views/Shared/testUUU.vbhtml

What am I missing?

Comment: There is some lock type icon in your image just before the testUUU.cshtml
Make sure the file is included in your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same Issue before when I was dealing with Areas and I solved it by adding Area name in Ajax URL

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Users/user/GetUsrForm',
    success: function (data) {
        //
    }
});
```

The Action

```
public ActionResult GetUsrForm()
{
    var model = new UserMod();

    return PartialView("~/Areas/Users/Views/User/testUUU.cshtml");
}
```

Comment: I manage to get to the action, I just can't return the partialView

Comment: I did the same with Action and it worked with me (I edit my answer)

Comment: I tried both of these and they worked... Im confused to that the url managed to find the action but not the view. Anyways thanks, sorry for being sceptical at the bginning