# Setting Partial Page (View) search path in .NET Core Razor Pages and AJAX

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, razor-pages, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am having a problem **setting the 'Search Path' for my Partial Pages (Views)** in my .NET Core 3.1 app. When I place the `_SomePartialPagePartial.cshtml` in the default search path directories (/Pages/Shared/ or /Views/Shared/), or in the same directory as the calling Razor page, the AJAX script calls the `public async Task<PartialViewResult> OnPostSomeMethodPartial(string ID, string ID2, ...)` and returns the view with `return Partial("_SomePartialPagePartial", SomeDataModel)` as expected.

But, when I place the `_SomePartialPagePartial.cshtml` file in another directory, the Razor page cannot find it.

The reason I want to place the Partial Page in another directory is for organizational purposes. I am using Areas to organize the project and would like to keep the partial pages in certain directories. For example, my structure is:

```
Areas
  Area1
    Models
    Pages
    Partials
    Services
  Area2
    Models
    Pages
    Partials
    Services
etc.
```

I would like to add a 'Partials' directory to certain Areas (i.e. Areas/Area2/Partials) and place the related partial pages there. The complexity arises when I try to reference a partial page in Areas/Area2/Partials from a Razor Page in Areas/Area1/Pages. In this case, the Razor page CANNOT find the partial file.

I already tried appending the search path in the Startup.cs file (as described in https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/partial-pages) but that doesn't seem to work?? The `options.PageViewLocationFormats` path added via `services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options => ...` does NOT append the path search array as verified in the debugger.

Perhaps the best solution would be to allow setting the directory of the partial file directly in the call (i.e. `Partial("<optional path>/_SomePartialPagePartial", SomeDataModel)` or `Partial("_SomePartialPagePartial", <optional path>, SomeDataModel)`). An enhancement?

Anyway, any help/suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated... :)

P.S. I am using the latest/updated version of VS 2019 (Version 16.11.3).

Comment: You'd better to put the partial views into one folder.Since different areas' pages will call the partials from other areas,so it is no need to separate partial views to different folders.

Comment: Yes, that's what I have been doing (as I described above). But it would be nice to have the option NOT to have to dump ALL the partial pages into a single directory. I guess I am looking for a better way to organize... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use below code.

```
public IActionResult OnPostSomeMethodPartial(string ID, string ID2, ...)
{
    // var model = new yourModelClass();
    // if you want use model, you can use like below
    // return PartialView("~/Areas/Area1/Partials/testPartialsPage.cshtml",model);
    return PartialView("~/Areas/Area1/Partials/_SomePartialPagePartial.cshtml");
}
```

***For more details, you can refer below post.***

[Application can't find view when using areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529518/application-cant-find-view-when-using-areas)

Comment: @Peter that works great. Funny thing is, I tested with the explicit path like you suggested above but simply forgot to add the .cshtml extension, which obviously didn't work. Still... It would be nice if the recommended solution of appending the search path in the Startup.cs would work (so if I ever move the view to another area, I won't have to track it down and change every reference), but I guess this is a good trade off. Tks... :)

Comment: @MicJarek If you think my solution useful to you,could pls accept as answer,tks.

Comment: thanks and sorry about the accept part.... I'm still a newbie to StackOverflow but learning ... :)

Comment: @MicJarek np，welcome^_^

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this issue on **.NET 6** when trying to include a partial view within a razor page with customized location formats.
I found answers that suggest deriving the `RazorViewEngine` and customizing the `PartialViewLocationFormats`, which in **.NET 6** isn't applicable since no such property exists anymore.

Yet, it turned out to have a different approach. If you navigate to the definition of the `RazorViewEngineOptions` and take a look at the comments, you'll find out that the one describing `PageViewLocationFormats` says:

> Gets the locations where `RazorViewEngine` will search for views (such as layouts and partials) when searched from the context of rendering a Razor Page.

So, to match the following configuration pattern:

```cs
options.ViewLocationFormats.Clear();
options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Gui/Views/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Gui/Views/Shared/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
options.AreaViewLocationFormats.Add("/Gui/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
options.AreaViewLocationFormats.Add("/Gui/Areas/{2}/Shared/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
```

I added one more line,

```cs
options.PageViewLocationFormats.Add("/Gui/Views/Shared/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
```